# How to fix Part::pkspec1: The expression cannot be used as a part specification?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, table

When I try to change the t parameter an error occurs, i want to solve hyperbolic pde by explicit FTCS.
Convection (transfer) equation.
Wolfram version - 12. The same problems arise with other methods, such as Lax-Wendroff or Richtmyer, so I will give the simplest example with FTCS.

```
h      = 0.05;
tau = 0.05;
T = 0.1;
L = 1;
n = L / h;
t = T /tau;
phi[x_] := Piecewise[{{x/0.6, 0 <= x < 0.6}, {(L - x)/(L - 0.6), 
     0.6 <= x < 1}}, 0];

Clear[u, c, A, pos, solution];

solution[x_, t_, c_] := N[phi[x - t  c h / tau]];
pos = Table[N[(j - 1)*h], {j, n}];
A[c_] := Table[
   N[solution[(j - 1)*h, (i - 1)*tau, c]], {i, t}, {j, n}];

(* Explicit FTCS method *)
ExplicitFTCS[phi_, c_, L_, T_, h_, tau_] := Module[{U, n, t},
   n = L / h;
   t = T/tau;
   U = Table[0, {i, t}, {j, n}];
   
   Do[U[[i, 1]] = 0,                                {i, t}];
   Do[U[[1, j]] = phi[(j - 1)*h], {j, n}];
   
   Do[U[[i + 1, j]] = 
     U[[i, j]] - c/2 * (U[[i, j + 1]] - U[[i, j - 1]]),
    {i, t - 1},
    {j, 2, n - 1}
    ];
   Return [U];
   ];

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{Table[{pos[[j]], A[c][[time, j]]}, {j, n}], 
   Table[{pos[[j]], 
     ExplicitFTCS[phi, c, L, T, h, tau][[time, j]]}, {j, n}]}],
 {c, 0, 1}, {time, 1, t}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `{time, 1, t}` will result in a continuous `time`, but you've used `time` as index of `List`, so what you need is `{time, 1, t, 1}` in `Manipulate`. See the document of `Manipulate` for more info.

Comment: @xzczd thank you very much you saved my time